# What will happen to a TCP/UDP serversocket when I switch wifi network?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, wifi

what will happen to the serversocket in my app when I suddenly change the wifi network? I guess it will shut down since my device will get a new IP, at least in TCP, is the UDP MulticastSocket prone to this as well? And how to end the previous Server socket thread and start a new one when the network changes? One solution is using time outs, another is using a flag that will indicate whether the infinite loop should end or not but since listening to a socket is a blocking function it will produce an exception/error anyways.

Any thoughts will be appreciated! :)

**EDIT:** sample of my server thread.

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4445);
while(true){
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    ObjectInputStream in  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    Object obj = in.readObject();
    Log.i("TAG", "Received: " + obj.toString());
    in.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCPIP connection will break. So client would have to connect again.

UDP will be ok provided your IP does not change after reconnection. Of course if you transmit UDP its not going to make a difference for that machine.

You should get an exception in case of TCPIP which you can handle.

Comment: Its been a whiel since I've studied this: Doesn't UDP establish some kind of connection first? Randomly blasting UDP packets with no connection just doesn't seem like it would work

Comment: @TheLQ : as far as i know it just transmits a packet with destination ip and port. It does not guarantee delivery. Its upto the network infrastructure to deliver the packet. As it is connection-less it does not get affected by network failure.

Comment: @TheLQ UDP is a connectionless protocol, so no connection is established.  (it is possible to call connect() on a UDP socket but all that does is set a default IP address/port for send() to send to, it doesn't actually change the logic of anything)

Comment: what is the exceptions name I should look for?

Comment: @MikeMokkas : it would be IOException.

Answer (score 1):

UDP sockets that are not bound to the address will remain open, as they are stateless. TCP listening sockets not bound to the address will remain open as well.

Conntected TCP sockets may be severed (RST) or just linger until a timeout hits.

It is a little known fact that IP mandates it that a device by default will accept packets directed to any address it has configured on any interface, no matter on which interface the packet arrives. If this were not so, routing would be broken. One can use packet filters to filter out packets with non-matching addresses depending on the interface.

Comment: Please check edit.
So when I change network my ServerSocket wont close but what will happen with the `socket = ss.start()`? Will that make my serversocket bound? And will my application throw an error and force close? How to overcome this problem, what is the exception I should watch for?

Comment: Is it fair to summarize this answer as, "listening sockets that specified INADDR_ANY (0) for the bind call will not be broken. But active TCP sockets that are in a connected state will break." Not familiar with Android, I'm assuming that "new ServerSocket(4445)" above binds to port 4445 on IP=0.

Comment: @selbie: They don't break neccessarily: For example I've set the timeout for SSH between my own machines to several hours. If I leave the house with my laptop, a SSH still open, connect to a foreign network, then after returning home, while still in the timeout, SSH connections simply continue. The point is: IP addresses are not bound to interfaces, but to hosts. Setting a IP address for a interface has actually to do with routing, i.e. on which device to send out packets for a specific subnet (first).