# Will an UDP client socket still usable if the network changes?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I got a program which transmit data through UDP and runs on phones. I found that when the network changes (for example joined another wifi), the socket will not be usable, if I called `send()`, "Network is unreachable" error will happen.

Since UDP is stateless, I thought the network changing seems harmless to the transition, but now I'm suspecting whether I'm wrong.

So, will an UDP client socket still usable if the network changes? If yes, what could lead to a "Network is unreachable" error? If not, does the "re-create-a-socket" the only way to restore the transition?

P.S. The program uses linux socket API and written in C.

Comment: A UDP socket may be stateless but it still has to be bound to a local adapter in order to transmit/receive data. So if the bound adapter changes, the socket may not work anymore. A recreate is the safest option.

Comment: In my case, it changes from a wifi to another, which should use the same adaptor...But I got your point and thank for you suggestion.

Comment: UDP is stateless but sockets aren't. As soon as you `send()` or `recv()` or friends, you are bound to a specific local IP address. If that ceases to work, so does your socket.

Comment: When you change WiFi, the IP address will be changed. If the UPD was created with `bind()` to `0.0.0.0` and no `connect()` was executed on it, it should not be affected by the changed IP address. Otherwise, it will be connected to a default IP address for sending (which will most probably be the old WiFi address) and `send()` will fail. Check [this SO where this is discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359703/what-will-happen-to-a-tcp-udp-serversocket-when-i-switch-wifi-network). re-crate is standard way to deal with this type of failures.